# How could I find out what sample rate/bit depth my headphones are capable of?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I'm using some USB headphones (Sennheiser GSP 350) and want to make sure that I am using the highest sample rate and bit depth possible for them. I ran `pacmd list-sinks` and it said that I'm using 16 bit 48000Hz (s16le 2ch 48000Hz). How can I make sure that this is the best option available?

If it wasn't obvious already, I'm using Linux with Pulseaudio/ALSA.

Comment: Do you ever listen to anything recorded at any higher sample rate or bit-depth? WAV files of this quality are approximately 11.5MB per minute. If all you ever listen to is MP3, AAC or any other compressed format, then you are wasting your time looking for "the best". You already don't have it as source. Also bear in mind most people can't actually tell the difference between 48k WAV & 128-bit MP3, even on good speakers. [Sorry if this sounds negative, but so many people are chasing unicorns they don't know don't exist.]

Comment: Headphones (and microphones and loudspeakers) are *analog* devices. There is no clearcut maximum rate; reproduction simply slowly drops above the design frequency. Use your ears: if you hear a difference, use the higher settings, if not, and you wish to conserve bandwidth/disk space, opt for lower settings.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik These are USB headphones. They have their own DAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For USB devices, all possible parameters are listed in `/proc/asound/cardX/stream0`.